# Why are pronouns always given in the same order? I, you, he, etc?

Tags: personal-pronouns, conjugation

**Not just English**

Why are pronouns when conjugating verbs always given in the same order.

- I
- You
- He
- She
- We
- You Plural
- They (or he's and she's depending on the language)

Does anyone know?

Comment: Good question.  This is just a guess, but to me they seem to be ordered on two levels, from the personal to the impersonal and from the singular to the group.  So we work from the singular: speaker (I) to the individual addressed (you) to the other not addressed (he/she/it); thence to the group of which the speaker is a member (we) to the group spoken to (you plural) to the group not spoken to but spoken of (they).  I'm looking forward to a knowledgeable answer...

Comment: First off, they are not [proper nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun), they are [pronouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun). Secondly, think 1st person, 2nd person, 3rd person, then the order is self-explanatory. (Or just read what @PSU said). Lastly, as you say yourself, this is not specific to English. The question might be a better fit for the [Linguistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics) site (whether or not it would be considered too basic there is a different question).

Comment: Sorry about the proper nouns bit I know that. I just find it difficult sometimes with words. Also I put that sentence in about not being english specific becasue I was unsure if it was a correct site to put this in. I'm happy for it to be migrated if thats necessary.

Comment: @PSU, I think you are right about the personal -> impersonal as the fundamental ordering here: as RegDwight says of course we call these 1st (I, we), 2nd (you), 3rd person (he/she/they). I wonder however whether some languages / cultures might mix the singular & plural rather than our convention of enumerating the singular & then starting again at 1st person plural.

Comment: While it is common to list them in this order when speaking, from my experience, it have found it different when written. In a textual form, it is common to create a grid/table, 2 columns and 3 rows. left column is singular pronouns, right column is plural pronouns.  1st row is 1st person, 2nd row is 2nd person, and 3rd row is 3rd person.

Answer (score 3):

It is the same in all other Indo-European languages I know. The perspective of any human being is with himself in the center: *I*. In any conversation, which is where language is important, there must be another human being present to whom I speak: *you*. Then we might discuss someone else: *he/she/it*.

The second set of pronouns is the same but in plural: I as an individual am a more basic, more important unit to myself than my group, *we*, which consists of several people. It is only logical to use the same order with plural pronouns as the one that is used with singular pronouns.

In Latin, there is a set of demonstrative pronouns for each of the three perspectives:

> *Hic* = that which is closer to myself than to any of the other persons
>
> *Iste* = that which is closest to you
>
> *Ille* = that which closest to him

This is how they were originally used, when pointing to objects in the physical world ("deictically"); but they have acquired different nuances and their meanings have shifted a bit. In English, we only have two of those:

> *This* = that which is closest to me or to you-and-I
>
> *That* = that which is closest to you or him

Their meanings have shifted a bit as well.

Comment: surely you plural would come before he / she in that circumstance?

So this relates to first person, second person, third person then?

Comment: @Wes: Well, I don't know how prehistoric men came to this order. But apparently they found the pronouns for individuals more "primary" than those for groups. There may be a certain degree of arbitrariness in their choice.

Answer (score 0):

It is a mostly arbitrary convention established by Latin grammarians, and hence employed by scholars of most European languages. I believe that the Arab grammarians listed Arabic verb forms in the order he/she, you, I.

There is a somewhat natural sequence, as others have pointed out; but the order in which that sequence is presented is mostly arbritrary.

Note that the order you are talking about is not part of English: it is part of talking about English. In English we usually put "I/me" last ("you and me", "John and I"), but have no firm order between 2nd and 3rd person.